# Fedex errors on shipping method, whether it's set to Test mode or not

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, shipping

I'm trying to set up two Fedex shipping methods in Expresso Store. I've set up a Fedex API account and have added the API Key, Password, Account number and Meter number that Fedex gave me. However, I always just receive the error "Meter number is missing or invalid.", even if I set the test mode to True.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The meter number is definitely the one that Fedex gave me, with no hidden spaces or any other mistakes. I'm running Store 1.6.0 on EE 2.3.0

Comment: Can you upgrade to Store 1.6.2 and let us know if the problem still persists? There were a few FedEx issues fixed in that release.

Comment: Aha! I've updated and now I'm getting 'Error communicating with shipping provider.'

Comment: I found this on stackoverflow - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298499/fedex-and-expresso-store-integration

I edited the line in the plugin and the output I get is:
soapenv:ServerSchema validation failed for request.5Schema validation failed for request.Invalid integer value: 19.68503937007919.685039370079Invalid integer value: 9.84251968503949.8425196850394Invalid integer value: 3.93700787401573.9370078740157

Comment: This seems to be the case for both test and production settings

Comment: That sounds like a bug with the weight not being rounded to the correct number of DP. Can you email support@exp-resso.com with the full output of your debuggin, so we can follow this up privately? Will post a solution here once we get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug fixed in Store 1.6.3.

- Fixed multiple issues and improved error handling of the FedEx shipping plugin (v1.6.2)
- Fixed a FedEx shipping driver error message when weights were stored as metric units in Store (v1.6.3)

https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_163